# Selenium WebDriver- How to control the speed of running the test cases

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I want to control the speed of the execution of running the test cases.

The WebDriver doesn't have a method setSpeed() (Selenium RC has this method). Also I am not using a selenium server.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking to explicitly control the 'speed' of the execution using methods,I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606602/948641) wherein a similar issue is discussed/answered.

Apart from that I think , that if we are looking at speed with efficiency/accuracy in mind,  we should follow good practices as in efficient [locator strategies](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#locating-ui-elements-webelements) , among others.

Or in some cases wherein if we have to interact with Ajax, we could use wait judiciously.More info [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

Hope this is useful :).

Comment: Another link to visit:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154982/is-there-any-method-in-webdriver-with-java-for-controlling-speed-of-browser