# Is there any method in WebDriver with Java for controlling speed of browser?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

When I use Selenium RC there is a method setSpeed as:

selenium.setSpeed("500");

What is the way to control speed of browser in Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: Do you know [Implicit Wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html)? You can also use WebDriverBackedSelenium and setSpeet (not recommended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Thread.Sleep(500)` (or equivalent) in whatever language you are using to run webdriver.  This will cause the thread to pause for an exact number of milliseconds.

Alternatively you can use *explicit* or *implicit waits* described [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html).

- Explicit waits allow you to define an `ExpectedCondition`.  Webdriver will check the condition every 500 milliseconds until it returns true, (after which execution will resume immediately).
- Implicit waits cause webdriver to keep retry attempting to locate something in the DOM.  Execution will resume immediately once the element is found.

Note that neither implicit nor explicit waits will guarantee a 500 millisecond pause.

Answer (score 12):

There is no longer any way to control the speed of each "step" in Selenium WebDriver. At one time, there was a `setSpeed()` method on the `Options` interface (in the Java bindings; other bindings had similar constructs on their appropriately-named objects), but it was deprecated long, long ago. The theory behind this is that you should not need to *a priori* slow down every single step of your WebDriver code. If you need to wait for something to happen in the application you're automating, you should be using an implicit or explicit wait routine.

Comment: What's the java code for implicit and explicit wait in Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: I think the most common need for the `setSpeed` is in _developing_ the automated tests.  I'm running into a situation where 2 tests pass, but if I run them as a suite, the 2nd test fails. I'm trying to debug what's going on, but the screen moves so fast that I can't see what's actually happening.

Comment: That's what breakpoints in an IDE (for static languages) or REPLs (for dynamic languages) are for.

Comment: Almost a year later and I'm back here.  I'm using Protractor now to develop tests for an Angular app.  The Promise system makes debugging even more difficult since my tests are just registering a series of commands, but I want to step through the execution of the commands.  That means putting breakpoints in the webdriver code as far as I can tell.

Comment: Back 3 years later to answer this question.  All I want is to play back a coworker's tests at a slower speed so I can verify them, not to cheat waiting for browser events by adding an explicit pause.

Answer (score 6):

There is no straight forward way. But there is a hack that you can use, you can override methods of webdriver and introduce a explicit sleep to slow down your tests eg. overriding findElement method

```
public class _WebDriver extends FirefoxDriver {

@Override
public WebElement findElement(By by) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return by.findElement((SearchContext) this);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better might be to use the webdriver FluentWait class alongside with ExpectedCondition. Sample can be found here:
http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/10/10/using-page-objects-with-selenium-and-web-driver-20/