# Running Selenium tests from team city/mspec

Tags: selenium, teamcity, mspec

We are running selenium webdriver tests that have been written using mspec.

We fire these tests from team city using the built in mspec runner.

This is using firefox locally on the server to run the tests.

We seem to get random results with varying numbers of successful and failing tests and we believe it's down to the execution speed. Our test suite has wait for elements but these don't always seem to have the desired effect.

Is there a way we can slow down the entire test suite execution to try and alleviate this problem?

Or is there a better approach to automating the running of these tests.

When we run them locally in visual studio, we can get them all green.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[setSpeed in Selenium WebDriver using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583445/set-speed-in-selenium-webdriver-ruby)

Here is an article which describes the problem of random failures and a better approach to minimize them.
http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html

Following webdriver documentation has details about Explicit and Implicit Waits... which help implement the same.
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Hope this Helps !!