# Workflow for Developing Functional Tests in Intern

Tags: intern

We are working here to fully integrate intern tests into our development. The first thing I am hitting setting up our intern with intern is how she should develop the tests. We are running locally on our macs with the selenium-server.jar, and when we run the functional test with runner.js in node, it flies by so fast we can't really see what is working. I really want to be able to slow it down (As I could with the selenium firefox extension) and hopefully highlight what it is selecting. The most important thing would be to just slow down the execution so we can see what is working. I am also finding debugging difficult, making it hard to know what is dying.

What is your workflow for developing functional tests with intern and is there any way to just slow the whole thing down?

node node_modules/intern/bin/intern-runner config=public/js/dojo/tt/tests/intern-config.js leaveRemoteOpen

I found the leaveRemoteOpen flag. This works!

Comment: You can add `.wait()` as a call after `this.remote.get()` or anywhere throughout your fluent calls and you can have as many as you like.

Comment: node node_modules/intern/bin/intern-runner config=public/js/dojo/tt/tests/intern-config.js leaveRemoteOpen

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583445/setspeed-in-selenium-webdriver-using-ruby/8606602#8606602

Answer (score 0):

```
this.remote.sleep(1000);
```

will do this for you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Huh?? The question clearly states: it flies by so fast we can't really see what is working. I really want to be able to slow it down (As I could with the selenium firefox extension) and hopefully highlight what it is selecting. The most important thing would be to just slow down the execution so we can see what is working.